# how to deal with highly skewed data with large number of zero values

Tags: r

I have a data set like below:

```
head(df)
##         Field.1 Complexity RQT.1 RQT.2 RQT.3 EQT.1 EQT.2 EQT.3 Outcome
## 1 Application 1          M    48    13     1  1594   945    50     832
## 2 Application 2          C     3     1     0     0     0     0       0
## 3 Application 3          C     1    31     2     0     0     0       0
## 4 Application 4          C     0     1     0     0     0     0       0
## 5 Application 5          M    11     5     0     0     0     0       0
## 6 Application 6          C     3     0     0     1     0     0      18
```

Now lets check the skewness of the numeric var:

```
library(e1071)
sapply(df.num,skewness)

RQT.1     RQT.2     RQT.3     EQT.1     EQT.2     EQT.3   Outcome 
5.228004  4.109652  6.842860  9.571051  7.520120 11.363172  9.922396
```

As we can see that the variables are highly right skewed....Also since we also have lot of zero values as observations.....Log transformation wont work in this case.....

How can i transform these numeric variables into near normal variables so that i can apply regression technique and then do predictions on the `outcome` variable as the dependent variable??

Comment: Most regression techniques do not require normal variables but only normal residuals. The larger the sample, the less important normal residuals become. Try the regression and check the residuals, not only for normality but also for heteroscedasticity etc.

Comment: Are you free in your choice of regression method? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244425/how-to-handle-0-inflated-data-set

Comment: @Bernhard......so should i run say the basic linear regression without any data transformation...and then check if the assumptions are being met?

Comment: I think you first need to characterise the distribution of `Outcome` and from that decide carefully whether this response is really continuous, categorical or binary.